# IoT - live video streaming from devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, live-streaming

I have a requirement which requires live streaming solution. Here is the requirement.

There will be 5000 IoT devices. Each device is capable of streaming live video. There will be about 1000 users. Each user can own 1 or multiple devices. Whenever the user wants to view live streaming of a device they own they should  be able to do so. So if user1 owns device1 only user1 should be able to view the live streaming from this device and no one else. The user credentials and device mappings are stored in a database. The device is connected to the server using MQTT protocol and the users connect to the server using HTTPS REST API.

How do I go about implementing the server for this. What protocol should I use?

I have been searching for a solution on the internet. I came across Amazon Media Live but it seemed limited in that I could only have 100 inputs per channel and 5 channels. Also the documentation states that the streaming inputs must already be streaming when channel is started. But my requirement is more like the streaming source would initiate streaming whenever required.

Does anyone have any idea on how to use AWS MediaLive for this task or if I should use MediaLive at all.

Peer to peer streaming of video from the device to the user's app is also a possibility. Assume the embedded device has linux os on it is there a viable peer to peer solution for this problem where the device stream the video to multiple user on mobile apps directly. I have no been able to find any such solutions on the internet.

Comment: This question is far too broad to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DXS (Data Stream Exchange system), and also you can look at this tech talk which will explain you how to do it 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoDzfRU4rEU&list=PLZWI9MjJG-V_Y52VWLPZE1KtUTykyGTpJ&index=2&t=0s

Answer (score -1):

For anyone in future doing something similar, I did some more research on the internet and it seems like Amazon Kinesis Video Streams does what is required. I have not implemented anything yet but hopefully it will work well for the requirements.